# Class is changed before style

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

See the following snippet:

```js
$('div').click(function(){
  $(this).css('width', '10px').addClass('wide');
});
```

```css
div {width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: green;}
div.wide {width: 200px !important; transition: width 2s;}
```

```html
<div></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I would expect the style to be applied first, making it 10px wide, and then the class to be added causing it to expand to 200px. However this isn't the case. If you look in the inspector you can see the class attribute being changed before the style attribute. Why is this and how can I make it work the right way?

Thanks!

Comment: `If you look in the inspector you can see the class attribute being changed before the style attribute` I can't see that fast, they change at the same time

Comment: `$(this).css('width', '10px').promise().then(() => $(this).addClass('wide'));`

Comment: Maybe your computer is faster than mine. I can definitely see a difference.

Comment: What is your goal i could understand at all you have animation with which is  turning this div width 200px. Also your div starts 100px width Why you want 10px when you click on it with animation which is 200 width to your div?

Comment: My goal is to understand why the class is changed first when it should be changed after the style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try waiting a bit before adding the class, you will never see the difference in times between the two your computer is way too fast.

In the end this was a question more about the way javascript is async and doesn't render the DOM between each command. Placing the timeout there tells javascript it can do something else for now and switch context to rendering.

```js
$('div').click(function(){
  $(this).css('width', '10px');
  var smallBox = this;
  setTimeout(function(){
      $(smallBox).addClass('wide');
  }, 0);
});
```

```css
div {width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: green;}
div.wide {width: 200px !important; transition: width 2s;}
```

```html
<div></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The browser needs a reason to switch the context back to rendering the UI, so the time you put into the timeout doesn't matter. This is all because js is async and can't do two things at once, that is render and change variables.

Comment: A timeout of 0 is a pretty good idea. I get that it's asynchronous but isn't it weird that it always changes the class first?

Comment: I wouldn't say the class change is occurring first, maybe at the same time as you are changing the DOM elements and they are being applied at render time together.
possibly this is a better explanation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3982851/jquery-not-executing-in-correct-order

Answer (score 1):

The reason your method doesn't work is because jQuery `.css()` method doesn't allow callback function, that means the `.css()` and `.addClass()` will fire at the same time. What you can do is try using `.animate()` method instead.

**Example**

```js
$( "div" ).click(function() {
  $(this).animate({
    width: 10
  }, function() {
    $(this).addClass('wide');
  });
});
```

```css
div {width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: green;}
div.wide {width: 200px !important; transition: width 2s;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

Comment: Even though it doesn't use a callback it should still execute in order right?

Comment: Yes, the execution order is always starts from top to bottom and left to right, since the code is being executed so quickly 0.05s or even less you won't see any difference on your screen, the moment you click on it.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is asynchronous, it can do two jobs at the same time. You can use [`setTimeout`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) to resolve this problem:

```
$('div').click(function(){
   $(this).css('width', '10px');
  setTimeout(function(){ 
  $(this).addClass('wide');
 }, 3000);});
```

Comment: A timeout is a dirty workaround for people how don't understand callbacks.